# How to actually connect to my vps via Chromebook

Tags: vps, chromebook, mosh

I've been trying for a while now to connect to my Digital Ocean VPS via my Chromebook. This is for development when away from my desktop. 
I'd prefer to use mosh so I've tried downloading [mosh](http://mosh.org) and using it. Then I try using Secure Shell and that's beyond me.
Here's a few pictures to show the problems I'm having:

[image: ![basic set up to connect to vps via mosh]

I also insert my rsa private key into the 'add ssh key' popup.

[image]

But then I get the problem seen above? I dont have a passphrase but if I hit enter I get an error:

```
 ssh authentication failed: Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey

SSH Login failed.

Mosh has exited.
Press "x" to close the window.
```

Now I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but after working through a heap of how-to pages I still can't get anywhere.

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I was using my private key generated through PuttyGen on Windows. I needed to export this in a linux format before I could use it. After that I just did what I recorded above and it worked. 
If anyone is keen on learning how to do this and are beginners to the whole thing like me then I'm going to be putting a guide up on my website: [finbarmaunsell.com](http://finbarmaunsell.com)

Answer (score 1):

The error is explaining the problem, it want's your public key, not your private key.

```
ssh authentication failed: Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey
```

You're only ever supposed to give your remote hosts your public RSA key.

Comment: But in this situation the OP was using a mosh chrome client to connect to a remote server. The solution was, as described in his answer, to supply a Private key in OpenSSH format to the mosh client. It had to be converted to OpenSSH format first, using PuttyGen, because it was originally created using PuttyGen.